# Deduction guide with non-type template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, non-type-template-parameter

In this simplified example, how can I achieve this kind of deduction guide ?

```
template<bool even>
struct Num {
    const int i;
};

template<int i>
Num(int) -> Num<i%2>; // Num(2) -> Num<true> ;; Num(3) -> Num<false>

int main() {
    const Num a{3};
}
```

Comment: There's no way.

Comment: What would you like to achieve?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Ok, I suspected that, thanks for you attention. I'll try to find another kind of helper or data structure.

Comment: @PepijnKramer OpenGL have data structure which can be interleaved or not. I want to implement iterator on such data. And I search a way to correctly set a std::contiguous_iterator or std::random_access_iterator to optimise copy method through std::copy.
Contiguous iterator or not depend on 'stride' parameter. I can put the 'stride' directly in the template, but I try to do not. I think is more idiomatic but I'm stuck ^^'.

Comment: For templates/static polymorphism to work you need to be able to know the interleaving at compile time. At runtime you either need some kind of runtime polymorphism somewhere and a factory that selects the correct instance.